# Representing multiple work visits to same location in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, relationship-class

How can I get ArcMap to summarize and display multiple feature 
records for the same address location?

Comment: What license and version (10sp2?) level are you with ArcMap

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq]

Answer (score 4):

Create a Relationship Class (ArcEditor & ArcInfo Licence Level only)

Example of a relationship (not specific to your question but in general terms)

[image]

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//004t00000003000000.htm

Then you can summarize the data on one location